# Matplotlib - tooltips on mouse hover

Tags: python, matplotlib, tooltip

Here is what I tried:

```
def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print 'onpick3 scatter:'

fig.scatter(t, p, color='b', zorder=10, label='label', picker=True)
fig.legend(loc=fills_legend_pos[index])
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
```

And the error

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

Edit: fig is of type AxesSubplot, and is instantiated like this

```
fig = plt.subplot2grid((i, i), (j, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=i)
```

What is the easiest way to add tooltips on my scatterplot? Please note that I want to keep my current framework, with calling fig.scatter, as these scatters are overlaid on an existing figure.

Comment: how is `fig` defined? despite calling it `fig` it appears to be an object with no `canvas` attribute!

Answer (score 2):

`subplot2grid()` returns an `Axes` object, use it's `figure` attribute to get the figure object:

```
import pylab as pl
axes = pl.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
axes.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py:746: DeprecationWarning: using `oa_ndim == 0` when `op_axes` is NULL is deprecated. Use `oa_ndim == -1` or the MultiNew iterator for NumPy <1.8 compatibility

and the tooltips don't show.